How to install the latest podman on Linux without building from source?
There are 22 dependencies necessary to build podman from source on Ubuntu/Debian. Unfortunately, the apt package manager contains only the 3.4.4 version of Podman which is very much out-dated.
I would like to install the latest version of podman in an easier and a more "storage economical" way. For example, installing only the essential binaries.

I have found the https://github.com/mgoltzsche/podman-static repository, where the podman binaries are provided and statically linked.
Installation steps

Download the statically linked binaries of podman and its
dependencies:
curl -fsSL -o podman-linux-amd64.tar.gz https://github.com/mgoltzsche/podman-static/releases/latest/download/podman-linux-amd64.tar.gz

Install the binaries and configuration on your host after you've
inspected the archive:
tar -xzf podman-linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo cp -r podman-linux-amd64/usr podman-linux-amd64/etc /


Uninstallation steps
If you are not using the podman binaries anymore, then free up the container storage with:
sudo podman system reset

After that, remove all the copied binaries:
sudo rm -rf /etc/containers/*
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/systemd/system/podman*
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/systemd/user/podman*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/{crun,fuse-overlayfs,fusermount3,pasta,pasta.avx2,podman,runc}
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/podman

Reference: https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/21382

I should point out that obtaining your infrastructure software from random people on the internet (although Max Goltzsche looks like a perfectly nice chap) is not without its risks.

@RichardHuxton Yes, very true. Sometimes, you need to pay for conveniences. I still hope that one day Debian/Ubuntu will support a newer version of podman.

Well, it's more a case of podman needs to behave like a proper infrastructure project and provide years of stability. There is still a ridiculous amount of churn.
